# Inconsistent behavior of gOverlaps and gTouches when polygons intersect at a point

Tags: r, polygon, computational-geometry, r-sp

I have two examples of `SpatialPolygons` (from package [sp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html)) that intersect at a single point. According to the help pages for `gOverlaps` and `gTouches` (from package [rgeos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html)), in this situation `gOverlaps` should return `FALSE` and `gTouches` should return `TRUE`. In other words, `gOverlaps` should only be true when the two polygons share some non-zero area, and `gTouches` should only be true when the two polygons only touch at one or more points along their boundary. This behavior holds for Example A below, but the opposite occurs for Example B below.

First, here's a helper function to create `SpatialPolygons` objects:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

spatial.polygon <- function(coord.vec, ID)
{
   SpatialPolygons(
      list(Polygons(list(Polygon(matrix(coord.vec, byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2))), ID = ID))
   )
}
```

Now for the examples.

---

## Example A:

Here are a square and a diamond that overlap at exactly one point:

```
square <-
   spatial.polygon(
      c(0, 0,
        0, 2,
        2, 2,
        2, 0,
        0, 0),
      ID = 'square'
   )

diamond <-
   spatial.polygon(
      c(3, 0,
        2, 1,
        3, 2,
        4, 1,
        3, 0),
      ID = 'diamond'
   )
```

Here's a plot of the square and diamond:

[image: square and diamond]

Here are the results of various **rgeos** functions tested on the square and diamond:

```
> gIntersects(square, diamond)      # Should be TRUE. Is TRUE.
# [1] TRUE
> gIntersection(square, diamond)    # Should return a point. Returns a point.
# SpatialPoints:
#   x y
# 1 2 1
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA 
> gOverlaps(square, diamond)        # Should be FALSE. Is FALSE.
# [1] FALSE
> gTouches(square, diamond)         # Should be TRUE. Is TRUE.
# [1] TRUE
```

So, for **Example A**, `gOverlaps` and `gTouches` behave as expected.

---

## Example B:

Here are a rectangle and a trapezoid that intersect at exactly one point:

```
rectangle <-
   spatial.polygon(
      c(1.00, 1.46,
        2.10, 1.46,
        2.10, 0.70,
        1.00, 0.70,
        1.00, 1.46),
      ID = 'rectangle'
   )

trapezoid <-
   spatial.polygon(
      c(1.5, 5.0,
        5.0, 5.0,
        5.0, 0.7,
        2.5, 0.7,
        1.5, 2.6,
        1.5, 5.0),
      ID = 'trapezoid'
   )
```

Here's a plot of the rectangle and trapezoid:

[image: rectangle and trapezoid]

You can verify mathematically that the rectangle and the trapezoid do in fact intersect at exactly one point. Here are the results of various **rgeos** functions tested on the rectangle and trapezoid:

```
> gIntersects(rectangle, trapezoid)      # Should be TRUE. Is TRUE.
# [1] TRUE
> gIntersection(rectangle, trapezoid)    # Should return a point. Returns a point.
# SpatialPoints:
#     x    y
# 1 2.1 1.46
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA 
> gOverlaps(rectangle, trapezoid)        # Should be FALSE. Is TRUE.
# [1] TRUE
> gTouches(rectangle, trapezoid)         # Should be TRUE. Is FALSE.
# [1] FALSE
```

So, for **Example B**, the results of `gOverlaps` and `gTouches` are the opposite of the expected results.

---

## The Question:

For **Example B**, why are the results of `gOverlaps` and `gTouches` the opposite of the expected results? Could this be a problem with machine precision?

Comment: This email: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2016-June/024519.html and the blog post it refers to might help. Look up scale factor.